# jquery > Adding class to dynamically created selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to add a class to a row that I generated with the jTable plugin, however I need to add it to certain rows that have a `<p>` with a class "highlighted" on the items I need to change the row's background. These I generate at the same time I generate the table.
I'm using this:

```
$( ".highlighted" ).parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
```

But it's not working... I'm assuming because it can't find the class I'm referencing. How can I fix this? Or is there any other way to do this? 
Thanks in advance

****edit****
Here's how I use the jTable plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('#items').jtable({
        title: 'Items',
        actions: {
            listAction:list.php
        },      
        fields: {
            picture: {
                title: 'Picture',
                width: '1%',
                display: function (data) {
                    if(data.record.picture!=null){
                        return '<img src="'+data.record.picture+'"/>';
                    }   
                }
            },
            item: {
                title: 'Item ID' ,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                width:'1%'
            },
            itemname: {
                title: 'Item Name' ,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                width: '30%'
            },
            status: {
                title: 'Status',
                display: function(data){
                    var status=data.record.status;
                    if(status=="Y"){
                        return data.record.status;
                    }
                    else {
                        return "<p class='highlighted'>"+data.record.status+"</p>";
                    }

                }
            }                   
        }
    });
    $('#items').jtable('load');
    $(".highlighted").parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
});
```

You can see I add the class in the status field.

Comment: can you show the dom you are working with? also, where is the above code ran from (document ready? an event?)? if you could provide a jsfiddle, that would help people help you

Comment: If you're generating the rows, just add the class at time of creation?

Comment: I'm using a plugin to make the table, that's why I can't add the class directly.

Comment: @smerny I just added the code I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the class after you create the `row` ..

And it is a better idea to use `closest` instead of `parent`

```
$( ".highlighted" ).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your markup, but maybe your DOM navigation isn't correct? Try using `closest()`, which will return the first ancestor matching the passed selector (in this case a `tr` element):

```
$(".highlighted").closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: The thing is I've tried adding another class to itself but it doesn't do it. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

```
$('tr:has(p.highlighted)').addClass('highlight')
```

or use the [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method

```
$('tr').has('p.highlighted').addClass('highlight')
```